# general evaluation for $\left \lfloor \frac{3^n}{2^k} \right \rfloor$ and properties

Tags: combinatorics

I considered the identity $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}2^r = 3^n$.

Hence $\left \lfloor \sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}2^{r-k} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{3^n}{2^k} \right \rfloor$. but now i am stuck.

Can we evaluate this value any better?

Thanks

Comment: What *any better* are you thinking of ? This is a quite simple expression.

Comment: I think it should be $\lfloor \sum_{r=0}^k\binom{n}r 2^{r-k} \rfloor$. I am pretty sure this cannot be simplified.

Comment: I thought it might be possible to find an expression without the floor value function. I guess probably not.

Comment: I edited the LHS (typo) from $\left \lfloor \sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{k}{r}2^{r-k} \right \rfloor$ to $\left \lfloor \sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}2^{r-k} \right \rfloor$. does it change something?